# DevExpress lookupedit repository item add new row in Xtra Grid View in first row

Tags: c#, devexpress, bindingsource, gridcontrol, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a devexpress gridcontrol with 5 columns. The first column is a lookupedit repository with some data, let say with CarTypes. 
To load data in grid I am using a `BindingSource`. In this `BindingSource.DataSource` I have load a `IList<Cars>`

and then 
added this binding source in dataSource of my gridcontrol
like bellow

```
BindingSource _carsBindingSource = new BindingSource();

private void BindData(IList<Cars> data)
{
            _carsBindingSource.DataSource = data;

            carsGridControl.BeginUpdate();
            carsGridControl.DataSource = _carsBindingSource;
            carsGridControl.RefreshDataSource();
            carsGridControl.EndUpdate();
 }
```

I have a button to add new line in my grid "Add new car" and add a new line in _`carBindingSource`

```
    private void AddNewRow()
    {
                _newRow = true;
                _carsBindingSource.AllowNew = true;
                Cars newCar = new Cars();
                newCar.CarType = new CarType();            
                _carsBindingSource.Add(newCar );
                //_carsBindingSource.Insert(0,newCar);


   }
```

Now I want to add the new line in the first row of grid.

I use `Insert`

```
_carsBindingSource.Insert(0,newCar);
```

But it didn't work. The `lookupedit repository` can't load data.

With `_carsBindingSource.Add(newCar);` it works fine

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: what is this line word means??? Now you have written your question well but still not clear what you asking..

Comment: You have right @NiranjanKala. Actualy I want to add a new row in my carsBindingSource BUT in the first row of grid. I use carsBindingSource.Insert(0,newCar) but did not work correctly

Comment: Actualy I found a solutions.The problem was in GridView_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) event where I change the AllowEdit value (e.Column.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;). .Add(object), .Insert(0,object) is same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualy I found a solutions.
The problem was in GridView_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) event 
where I change the AllowEdit value (e.Column.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;).

```
private void gridView_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{
    string cName = e.Column.FieldName;
    GridView gv = sender as GridView;

    if (cName == "CarType.IdApi")
    {
        if (isNewRow)
        {
            Cars cars= (Cars)gv.GetRow(e.RowHandle);

            int a = e.RowHandle;
            if (cars.ID== 0 && e.RowHandle == 0)
            {
               e.Column.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;
            }
            else
            {
               e.Column.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;
            }
         }        
     }
}
```

When I use `Insert(0, new Car)` then because of second row whitch has value 
the `AllowEdit` was false; 
So I remove `else` code and it works

```
private void gridView_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        string cName = e.Column.FieldName;
        GridView gv = sender as GridView;

        if (cName == "CarType.IdApi")
        {
            if (isNewRow)
            {
                Cars cars= (Cars)gv.GetRow(e.RowHandle);

                int a = e.RowHandle;
                if (cars.ID== 0 && e.RowHandle == 0)
                {
                   e.Column.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;
                }
             }        
         }
    }
```

So finlay I found that `bindingSource.Add(object)` and  `bindingSource.Insert(0,object)` is same!

I apologize for my english!!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, consider using an intermediate list for your car types:

```
private List<CarTypes> _CarTypes;

// Elsewhere in the code...
_CarTypes = GetCarTypes();
```

And then in the form load event, be sure this is bound to the data source:

```
repositoryLookupItemCarTypes.DataSource = _CarTypes;
```

With this, the grid should now automatically manage the instantiation and selection of the CarType object for each Cars object.  You can omit this line when you add a car to the grid:

```
newCar.CarType = new CarType();
```

In the designer, I think it helps to alter the `DisplayMember` Property of the repository Item.

With this setup, any Car added to your grid should automatically have the CarType as a populated Lookup Edit.

If any of this is unclear, let me know.  I did a quick and dirty solution to test this, and I obviously can't post it all, but I can tell you it did work with both `Add` and `Insert`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I have already all this. With BindingSource.Add(newCar) works fine but the problem is the new line goes in the end row of grid and I want to add in first row. With Insert(0,newCar) it goes to first row but I must to click in other columns a lot of times till reload data in lookupedit repository, I try bindingSource.AddNew() command with Insert and now added 2 rows. One in first row and a row in end of grid but now works! I can't understand what happens

Comment: Well, I'm glad it works, at least.  For what it's worth, you can add the binding source at design time (on the form) rather than within the code.  Maybe you did that and only showed the code to illustrate it, but just in case...